# Web Api: Return JSON with EF Included Member Field Count but not Member Object Data

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Scenario: Complaint object can have many Votes. In the GET request for All Complaints, I want to return the Vote Count, and not each individual vote object with the Complaint in the API response.

Here's the main classes:

```
//Model: Complaint.cs
public class Complaint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    public int UpVoteCount=> Votes.Count(v => v.IsUpvote);
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
}


//Model: Vote.cs
public class Vote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpVote{ get; set; }
    public Complaint Complaint { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
}


//DbContext: AppDbContext.cs
....
public IQueryable<Complaint> ComplaintsWithData =>
        Complaint
            .Include(complaint => complaint.Votes)
            .AsNoTracking();

//ApiController: ComplaintsController.cs
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Complaint> GetComplaints()
{
      return _context.ComplaintsWithData.ToList();
}
```

In the current JSON response, I get the Vote count, however I also get each individual vote object's details as well (which I don't need in this call).

**Current Response:**

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "summary": "House was Stolen",
        "votes": [
            {
                "id": 146,
                "isUpvote": false,
                "creator": null
            },
                        {
                "id": 147,
                "isUpvote": false,
                "creator": null
            },
            ....
            ....
            ....
        ],
        "upVoteCount": 211,
    }
```

**Desired Response:**

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "summary": "House was Stolen",
        "upVoteCount": 211,
    }
```

I need to have the .Include(complaint => complaint.Votes) in the AppDbContext.cs file so that I can actually load the Votes to determine the Vote Count.

I do not want to store the Vote count as an actual database column.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I am using .NET Core 2.0 Web API with Entity Framework Core.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you shouldn't expose your database object through webapi.You should create DTO (data transfer object) and once you get results from database you should map results to DTO and return DTO as the response.
If you really need to expose your database object then you can try adding [JsonIgnore] attribute on List<Vote> Vots. I encourage you to go with DTO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OptIn on your class for members serialization:

```
//..
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//..

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Complaint
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("upVoteCount")]
    public int UpVoteCount=> Votes.Count(v => v.IsUpvote);
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
public List<Complaint> ComplaintsWithData()
{
    return this.DbContext.Complaints
        .Include(complaint => complaint.Votes)
        .Select(p => new Complaint
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            IsUpVote = p.IsUpVote,
            UpVoteCount = p.Votes.Count
        }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. Below are two of them:

You might consider **adding view models** - classes with the exact set of properties you would like to return to UI. You just need to **map your entity records to them**.

Or just **mark the properties you'd like to hide** from being serialized to your `JSON` or `XML` endpoint response **with [NonSerialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute**.

```
public class Complaint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [NonSerialized]
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    public int UpVoteCount=> Votes.Count(v => v.IsUpvote);
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
}
```